# Loading XML into Document object in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-browser, google-chrome

I am unable to load an XML file into a JavaScript Document in Google Chrome with the following function:

```
// load XML document based on whether the browser is IE or other browsers
function loadXMLDocument(url)
{
    var doc;

    if (window.ActiveXObject)   // IE
    {
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.load(url);

        alert('document loaded in IE');
    }
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
        doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);

        // this line seems to cause an error in Chrome
        doc.load(url);

        doc.onload = function()
        {
            alert('document loaded in other browsers except Chrome');
        }       
    }
}
```

This code works fine in IE6/7, FF2/3.x, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.load()` is not yet supported in WebKit. Consider using an XmlHttpRequest.

Reference: [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988)

Comment: +1. There is a DOMParser you can have from WebKit and Mozilla, but when you're fetching a resource the simple, straightforward thing to do should be a plain old XMLHttpRequest.